# jquery for placeholder having similar classes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve placeholder using jquery and css.

I am having 2 classes ".txt" and ".placeholder", but I use this class for multiple textboxes. I need the jquery action(hide the placeholder) on mouseover event.

HTML:

```
 <div class="placeholder">First Name</div>
 <input type="text" class="txt"/>

 <div class="placeholder">Last Name</div>
 <input type="text" class="txt"/>

 <div class="placeholder">City</div>
 <input type="text" class="txt"/>
```

CSS:

```
.txt
{
 height:40px;
width:300px;
margin-bottom:20px;
font-size:22px;
}

.placeholder
{
color:#DDD;
float:left;
position:absolute;
font-size:22px;
font-family:'Tahoma';
margin-top:7px;
margin-left:10px;
}
```

Please have a look at the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/39YJZ/2/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the action you want

Comment: Hide placeholder on mouseover event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to achieve this.

```
$('.txt').hover(function(){
    $(this).prev('div.placeholder').hide();
}, function(){
    $(this).prev('div.placeholder').show();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/39YJZ/5/)

As lee_mcmullen suggested the selector `'div.placeholder'` passed to the `prev` is optional.

```
$('.txt').hover(function(){
    $(this).prev().hide();
}, function(){
    $(this).prev().show();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/39YJZ/7/)

Comment: Don't necessarily need the selector in the call to `prev()` as prev() only gets the immediately preceding element.

Comment: @lee_mcmullen yes, but to be in the safer side

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.txt').hover(function(){
  $(this).prev().hide();
},
function(){
  $(this).prev().show();
})
```